# Socket Send and checking for user login in php?

Tags: php

First, I would like to check to see if a user is logged in.  If not, the user should be redirected to the login.php page.

Second, I would like to send a socket in PHP. What I would like to happen is when the mute button is selected, a message is sent to the computer instructing it to do so.

The purpose of this is for an app that I am creating but I'm not sure how to proceed.

```
<?php 

//session_start();

include("helper/DBOperation.php");

$dbObj = new DBOperation();

include("helper/check_user_login.php");

checkUserIsLogin();

?>
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're doing, and what you are asking.

Comment: Is the PHP code running on the same machine as the user who is sending the mute command?  You might want to try a desktop application language like C#.Net instead of PHP if you need control over sockets and catching events like hitting the mute button.

Comment: How can there be answers and **with upvotes** to this question?

Answer (score 3):

For the socket section I would suggest that you use JavaScript technologies like Node.js and Socket.io. 
Here are the links to the docs : [node documentation](http://nodejs.org) [socket.io](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io/wiki/)

This works well with a Php web site since you can use JavaScript on your client side code. You will have a node server running on another port on your computer that runs the Apache server.
BUT the thing is that I am not sure if you can access to the system's volume control from a node server. 
If it is a html5 video that you need to mute, you can do that with JavaScript.

Let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is:

In the DBOperation.php, the 264th line which says:

```
$data_provided = "not enough at all";
```

Change that to:

```
$data_provided = "provide enough, so that others can figure out what is going on";
```

Also, in the function checkUserIsLogin, pay attention to following lines:

```
function checkUserIsLogin()
{
  /*
specify what sending a socket to PHP means, and also what is the role of the mute button selection in the grand theme of things*/

 if($data_provided == "not enough at all")
    die("Sorry, too little data, please provide more information..");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are a novice.

1. It is up to you to decide if a user is logged in. Assuming Web based technologies, you need to read up about PHP sessions, HTML authentication, SSL etc.
2. A [socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket) need to be read up about in your case. Google it.
3. Before creating this app do a little playing and background reading
4. Get back to us when you have a better idea of the problem areas.